# What is the cheapest unique in Path of Exile?

Tags: path-of-exile

Are there any uniques that are worth doing the vendor recipe for 5 chance orbs? (1 white, 1 magic, 1 rare and 1 unique).

Comment: broadstroke, redbeak come to mind.  Those items frickin suck.

Comment: Oh and downvoters, can you explain why?  This is a totally valid question, he wants to know if any uniques are so bad that this recipe would be worth doing.

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc Redbeak is actually good sword to use to easily level with your new characters (because it's stats are pretty good for weapon with no level requirement). It's also a good weapon for CI spellcasters because that "100% damage increase when on low life" works for both attacks and spells, and as you may know CI builds are always on low life.   

I also agree that there was no reason to downvote this question. Then again, the economy might change in the future, and with it the answer.

Comment: @ChrisHatez If you are far enough to be able to spec into CI and your weapon would be Redbeak, you either rushed CI because you are on Default or you had the most terrible drop luck I have ever seen ;)  By the time you can afford to spec into CI in HC you'd have weapons about 40-45 Ilvls higher.  But it's low-leveling gear for sure, just that it generally takes me 2 hours to hit 20 so to me that gear is worthless

Comment: @ChrisHateZ You can't be low on life with CI - you're either at 100% or you're dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. I don't think there is any unique that's as cheap as 5 chances. Cheapest uniques are the ones that aren't very useful and with low rolls, and even those can be sold for at least 2 alchs (1 alch = 4 chances).

That's based on Hardcore League economy at least, i don't play default league so i don't know are their rates any different.

Comment: I'd have to diasgree. Araku Tiki (Coral Amulet) is definitely cheap enough to use for the chance recipe. You hardly ever see them sold because it's such a terribad item that the chance recipe is what everyone uses them for. Last time I bought one for the recipe I paid one jeweller's orb for it.

Comment: @Fambida That wasn't the case at the time i answered this question. That's something that has to be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are quite a few uniques that "suck so much" that noone uses them. There are not even some niche builds for most of these, simply because they're just **that bad.**

Most people do not even bother selling those to others, they just vendor them, but a lot of people still sell them. The introduction of the API, which allows to list items using premium stash tabs, has opened the market up for more people (*as most couldn't be bothered using the forums or some 3rd party software in order to sell those cheap uniques*).

If you want to find cheap uniques, just visit the [inofficial auction house of Path of Exile](http://poe.trade), select your league & the rarity, and press "Search". It will list ~50ish uniques, starting with the lowest prices. These uniques cost 1x "Orb of Alteration", so you could very well profit using this recipe. Just please, before vendoring it, make sure that you're not vendoring an incredibly good rare.